# Getting Empty Result while trying to read S3 bucket file using boto3

Tags: python, amazon-s3, boto3

I am trying to access a CSV file from S3 bucket by using the following code in python

```
s3=boto3.client('s3')
_data=s3.get_object(Bucket='ml-titanic-dataset',Key='test_data/test.csv')
_data['Body'].read().decode('utf-8')
```

I am getting the result as empty but i have data inside the mapped CSV file.

1. Is there anything missing
2. Am i doing the decoding right

when using print(_data), i get the following output

```
    {'ResponseMetadata': {'RequestId': 'YTTJTHCNKWKV72SA', 
'HostId': 'GGzZuluP68nAiPEAKIpc6W8n9wQLhq+yb4phZS5DugcjmLkMlmw4FXl+R5jXDAw56VX6AqaOYk8=', 
'HTTPStatusCode': 200, 
'HTTPHeaders': {'x-amz-id-2': 'GGzZuluP68nAiPEAKIpc6W8n9wQLhq+yb4phZS5DugcjmLkMlmw4FXl+R5jXDAw56VX6AqaOYk8=', 
'x-amz-request-id': 'YTTJTHCNKWKV72SA', 'date': 'Tue, 13 Feb 2024 07:03:02 GMT',
 'last-modified': 'Mon, 12 Feb 2024 16:31:53 GMT', 'etag': '"7533b82eae4b582610cbd68aa636b017"',
 'x-amz-server-side-encryption': 'AES256', 'accept-ranges': 'bytes', 'content-type': 'text/csv', 
'server': 'AmazonS3', 'content-length': '28629'}, 'RetryAttempts': 0},
 'AcceptRanges': 'bytes', 'LastModified': datetime.datetime(2024, 2, 12, 16, 31, 53, tzinfo=tzutc()),
 'ContentLength': 28629, 'ETag': '"7533b82eae4b582610cbd68aa636b017"',
 'ContentType': 'text/csv', 'ServerSideEncryption': 'AES256', 'Metadata': {},
 'Body': <botocore.response.StreamingBody object at 0x7fafcfb9caf0>}
```

assinging the data to the variable and accessing also give me empty result as shown

[image]

Comment: `print(_data)` and check what it returns.

Comment: What your last line `_data['Body'].read().decode('utf-8')` is supposed to do? You are not assigning its output to any variabile.

Comment: @Marcin, i did assigning the result to a variable and still i am getting empty result, please see my updated question